# How much of the API of an SDK does my sample application use

Tags: java, c++, class, function, code-coverage

I have an SDK called X and a couple of sample applications written in Java and C++ that uses the APIs from the SDK.

Bigger picture : To verify how much of the classes, functions, enum variables etc defined in the SDK is used by the sample apps.

I am fooling around with doxygen to do this, Can doxygen do this and is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: Use any standard profiler for java. It will give you `number of loaded class`, `number of times a method is entered and exited`, `number of time a class is used` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code of the SDK you can use [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) to do code coverage (just run your sample app as a JUnit test)